# How to select an inductor for 3rd overtone oscillator SIMPLIFIED way

Tags: inductor, oscillator, resonance

My question is at least approximate calculation of L1 inductor. With my design I have followed below SIMPLIFIED rules. Can someone correct any of my mistakes, if my component selection is proper? Crystal I plan to use is 27MHz load capacitance 9pF, frequency I desire is about 81MHz. I have only small space available on PCB.

1. I have seen in literature from Analog Devices, that C3 capacitor can be safely selected with a fixed value of at least 10 times the value of C2 capacitor and it should be ceramic NP0 material. In my case it should be above 180pF.
2. C2 should be same as C1, and about double of Xtal load capacitance.
   In my case 2 * 9pF = 18pF.
3. L1 should be tuned with C2 to about 2/3 of 3rd overtone frequency, which is in my case about 54MHz. The simplified calculation ignoring stray capacitance etc is:
   2/3 final frequency = 1 / (2*pi * SQRT(L * C))
4. L1 should be better quality, at least Qmin = 30; Rl < 1 Ohm; SRFmin = 100MHz

My schematics at this point is:

[image]

Your advice is very appreciated.

Comment: If the frequency you're after is actually 81MHz, would you consider an 81MHz XO instead ? Take a look at the part DSC1004CI5-081.0000 from Microchip ...

Comment: So what value did you get for the inductor and did you try it out?

Comment: This is easy to simulate on Falstad sim  with Crystal parameters for CLC

Comment: @AndyAka Andy I just received the PCBs and still did not build it. I have all the components but the inductor

Comment: @citizen Nice part! The other oscillators I looked at consume over 25mA, I did not know about your low power one. But still, my solution cost $1 less

Comment: @Tony Stewart I will keep looking, but so far failed to find CLC circuit or crystals there - maybe you ment to draw the whole thing from scratch

Comment: @EmbeddedGuy not sure how you're gonna do that given the 27MHz XO will cost you at least $1 and is hard to find in small quantities ...

Comment: An LTSpice simulation showed oscillation @ 81Mhz using your component values. This should give you very little satisfaction, because crystal parameters were crudely estimated. Crystal current was quite large, driving the crystal > 1mW power.

Comment: Take my advice too, but the XO, series mode takes more current but has higher overtone Q. yes I have some CLC parameters for 10 Mhz which I reduced L by ~9 to make 27 and 9 again for the 3rd harmonic. .. count up all the reactive parts and thats defines your risk to spurious modes

Comment: @citizen The crystal indicated in schematics cost $0.12/pc, the gate cost $0.04, the rest cost $0.06, totaling to $0.22, which is 1/6th of the pretty solution. My budget for the whole product is $3. If money is no object I would choose the Microchip solution, but looks like cannot afford it.

Comment: @EmbeddedGuy: Did you get the systemn work? I also try to design a 3.rd Overtone Oscillilator with ca. 80-90 MHz. I came to quite similar results for an ABRACOM ABM7-27, however it seems to be very difficult to simulate... Thx. a lot, Jo